# removing rows from a table from a result of groupby

Tags: sql

I have the following table
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f078/1

Okay so what I want do is GROUP BY `schoolid` and then count the number of kids in each school. This is easy. But I want to remove a school that has less then 10 kids who have `schoolinclude = 1`.  So basically, for a specific school, look at all the kids who have `schoolinclude = 1` and then count these kids. If the school has less then 10 kids, I want this school to be removed. I want to then return the original table with this school removed.

Whats the best way of going about this?

Comment: And how close you have been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it might be a school question so I'm not going to give the whole answer but:

Look into the HAVING clause http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Actually Im at work and I was just blanking out. However thank you for the link. I completely forgot about the having clause. I was trying to put the "count()" in the where clause and it was giving me an error that you cant use aggregate function in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `HAVING` clause to `count(students)` similar to this:

```
select *
from table_name
where schoolmident not in (SELECT schoolmident
                            FROM table_name
                            where schoolinclude = 1
                            group by schoolmident
                            having count(studentuid) < 10);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f078/18)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
   select schoolmident
   from table_name
   where schoolinclude = 1
   group by schoolmident
   having count(studentuid) > 9) as a 
      join table_name as b
      on a.schoolmident = b.schoolmident
```